# ionic-1 menu-close Doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

am using ion-side-menus in the ionic-1 project if I click side menu options the functionalities worked but side menu doesn't close. Is possible to access menu-close directive in the controller.

**Html:**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" menu-close on-touch="vm.goSechemeList()">
      <i class="icon ion-document-text"></i> {{'SCHEMES' | translate }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**Controller:**

```
function goSechemeList () {
  $log.log('click scheme list');
  Analytics.trackEvent(Track.Secure_schemelist);
  $state.go('secure.layout.schemes');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-click` instead `on-touch`

Like: `ng-click = "goSechemeList()"`

Hope this help:)

Comment: In controller use method like this $scope.goSechemeList  = function(){ 
$log.log('click scheme list');
  Analytics.trackEvent(Track.Secure_schemelist);
  $state.go('secure.layout.schemes'); } @ragu

Comment: vm as same $scope, I declared globally

Comment: oh i see,u forgot to close tag </ion-side-menu> in your code.please close it and try again @ragu